# How could I encrypt an SD card to store data on it?

Tags: encryption, aes, data-leakage, sd-card

I have some data I'd like to carry with me in an encrypted form onto an SD card, so I (and only I) can access it easily from any OS (or at least Windows, OSX and Ubuntu). **My idea was like:**

- Two partitions: one is a small FAT32 with live decryption program, another is hidden and encrypted and - once mounted with decryption key - appears as a FAT32 mount compatible with all OSes
- Data encrypted with something like AES-256.
- Three versions of decryption program: one for GNU/Linux, one for OSX and one for Windows.
- Ability to read and write (once mounted) the encrypted partition and to unmount it safely with no data loss.

How could I achieve this? I've already tried *LaCie PublicPrivate*, but it only supports OSX and Windows though.

Comment: Try TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt and its compatible equivalents.

Comment: Is it compatibile with the three OSes i mentioned?

Comment: Yes, TrueCrypt 7.1a is available for Windows, Linux and OSX.

Comment: And does it require some software to be l'installed on the machine, or once the SD Card is created it works out of the box?

Comment: Installation is mandatory. Please have a look at [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) yourself.